# whenever i run the application the data continuously get added to database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, csv, spring-mvc, spring-batch

**I am using Spring batch to dump data from csv file to database but whenever i run my springboot application the data from csv file got continuously appending to database.**

whenever i run my springboot application the data from csv file got continuously appending to database.

```
  @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

**applications.properties**

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema.sql
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy= ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

**itemreader**

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Covid> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Covid> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("Cdata.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Covid>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setDelimiter(",");
            setStrict(false);
            setNames(new String[] {"id","firstname",lastname,ph});
            setIncludedFields(new int[] {0,1,2,3});
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Covid>() {{
         setTargetType(Covid.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide more details of your configuration: ItemReader definition, application.properties file.

Comment: And please include a question, how is that undesired behavior and what are your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch framework is by default enabled and jobs run on every start of the Spring Boot application. To avoid processing of your input file on startup you can disable Spring Batch in application.properties:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```